# Create Program Code out of excel table in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

For a Macro, I want to create an automated `ATTRIB` Statement.

I have an exel Table with all variable names, formats, lables and lengths.

Now I want SAS to read each row and pass it into:

```
%LET Format_VARIABLE = FORMAT = &For  LENGTH = &len LABEL = "&lab";
```

Any ideas how to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a dataset (called `metadata`) containing all of you variable names (`vname`), formats (`vfmt`), lengths (`vlen`) and labels (`vlbl`) from Excel :

```
/* Create VNAME1-VNAMEx, VFMT1-VFMTx etc */
data _null_ ;
  set metadata end=eof ;
  call symputx(cats('VNAME',_n_),vname) ;
  call symputx(cats('VFMT',_n_),vfmt) ;
  call symputx(cats('VLEN',_n_),vlen) ;
  call symputx(cats('VLBL',_n_),vlbl) ;
  if eof then call symputx('VNUM',_n_) ;
run ;

%MACRO BUILD_ATTRIB ;
  /* Iterate over each set of macro variables and resolve into `attrib` statement */
  attrib %DO I = 1 %TO &VNUM ;
         &&VNAME&I format=&&VFMT&I length=&&VLEN&I label="&&VLBL&I"
         %END ;
         ;
%MEND ;

/* To use in a datastep */
data want ;
  %BUILD_ATTRIB ;
  set have ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working like a charm.